# OutOfBounds Exception in Android's HeaderViewListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have an adapter that extends *BaseExpandableListAdapter* , I attach it a footer and a header. the adapter's content is an *ExpandableListView*.

It seems to be working just fine most of the time and during all my tests. However, I can see several crashes that happened to some people.

The crash log points to *HeaderViewListAdapter* line 164. 
I'm not able to figure out the problem , and why it happens only relatively rarely. I was also unable to recreate the crash by myself .

(I did notice however that all the crashes were on **Android 6.0/6.0.1**)

The crash seems to be in the *HeaderViewListAdapter's* code in **line 164** , which is :

```
// Footer (off-limits positions will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException)
return mFooterViewInfos.get(adjPosition - adapterCount).isSelectable;
```

---

```
  java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException (ArrayList.java:255)
        java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:308)
        android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled (HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
        android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem (AbsListView.java:2525)
        android.widget.ListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem (ListView.java:3949)
        android.widget.AbsListView$ListItemAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (AbsListView.java:2452)
        android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:6079)
        android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal (View.java:6040)
        android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:22348)
        android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:6023)
        android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource (AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
        android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource (AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
        android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal (View.java:5977)
        android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (View.java:22260)
        android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (View.java:5963)
        android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal (View.java:5830)
        android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (View.java:22199)
        android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (View.java:5813)
        android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal (View.java:5792)
        android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEvent (View.java:22157)
        android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent (View.java:5757)
        android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5207)
        android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21209)
        android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
        android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5525)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: mFooterViewInfos.get(adjPosition - adapterCount) check before that such an element of index adjPosition - adapterCount exists.

Comment: but that's HeaderViewListAdapter's code(android inner class) , I can't make any changes to it

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could post the whole adapter class code

Comment: but HeaderViewListAdapter is an android's class. It is not a custom class made by me.

Comment: *I have an adapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter*, I am talking about **this** class

Comment: @BVtp Were you able to figure this out? I literally have the same exact problem and I'm ripping my hair out :(.